# Messed up "Google play services". How to reinstall them?

Tags: applications

I accidentally deleted my phone's Google Play Services app. So now, when I try to download apps on the Play Store, it says "No devices installed", and every time I try to install Google Play Services, it wont allow me to.

Can you help me? I've tried just about everything, and it still won't allow me to download anything. How would I get Google Play Services back working again?

Comment: Can you give us more information? Which phone do you have? Which version of Android do you have? How did you delete Play Services?

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted with custom recovery installed, flash new Google-apps package from OpenGapps which would reinstall the entire Google apps with framework and Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

You could just search for an `.apk` for the Google Play Services on Google Search.  And, install it as usual.